# In C++, is it allowed to cast to a derived class that only adds non-virtual methods?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, casting

I'd like to add non-virtual methods to an existing class `A` that I can't change. Therefore I create a class `B` inherited from `A` and add the methods I want. Now, if I have an object of type `A`, can I just regard it as an object of type `B`? Say, is the following code legal?:

```
class A { <...> };

class B: public A {
    void f();
  };

A a();
void g( const B& );
void h() { g( static_cast<B&&>(a()) ); }
```

It does compile and work, however I was wondering if it's guaranteed by the standard to work as expected. I don't see why not, yet it doesn't feel very clean..

Comment: No, the cast causes undefined behaviour

Comment: But `B a;` followed by a call to a function that takes an `A &` as an argument, as in `void foo(A & a);` and calling it IS legal and defined: `foo(a)` such that inside foo, if you really know that `a` is really a `b` (but how would you?), you can perform the cast.

Comment: Why do you want to cast an object into something it isn't?

Comment: @MikeMB: To be able to use a new method on it, which wasn't defined in the original class. Or to override an existing method.

Comment: So you need to add a function to an object `a` without changing the actual type of that object and without changing the class definition of `A`. Correct?

Comment: @MikeMB: Yeah, you could say so.

Answer (score 5):

That is undefined behavior. From [[expr.static.cast]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#2):

> An lvalue of type “cv1 B”, where B is a class type, can be cast to type “reference to cv2 D”, where D is a class
>   derived (Clause 10) from B, if a valid standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists (4.10),
>   cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1, and B is neither a virtual base class
>   of D nor a base class of a virtual base class of D. The result has type “cv2 D”. An xvalue of type “cv1 B”
>   may be cast to type “rvalue reference to cv2 D” with the same constraints as for an lvalue of type “cv1 B”.
>   **If the object of type “cv1 B” is actually a subobject of an object of type D, the result refers to the enclosing
>   object of type D. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

`a` isn't actually a suboject of an object of type `B` - it's really just of type `A`, so the behavior is undefined.

What's to stop you from simply adding a non-member function:

```
void f(A& );
```

If the answer is that you need to access `private` or `protected` members of `A`, then there was intent to make those members unaccessible to you!

Comment: Nothing stops me, it's just that by using a global function I lose one of the advantages of OOP.. Too bad C++ doesn't provide a solution to this problem.

Comment: @YaronCohen-Tal Sounds more to me like you discovered one of the disadvantages of OOP.

Comment: @YaronCohen-Tal: In a derived class, you can't access the `private` parts of a base class either. Encapsulation isn't broken by derivation.

Comment: @Yaron: What advantage of oop would you loose that way?

Comment: @YaronCohen-Tal That is a common misconception about OOP. See [Effective C++](https://epiportal.com/Ebooks/Addison.Wesley.Effective.CPP.3rd.Edition.May.2005.pdf) item 23.

Comment: @sbabbi: This is an interesting discussion, but I guess not one that fits into comments in SO.. Anyway, consider the following scenario: I want to inherit `std::shared_ptr` and override `oeprator*()` so that it throws an exception if the pointer is null. Sure, I can create a global function, but it would kind of miss the point..

Comment: @MikeMB: The same advantage you get in any function being a method rather than global function (beside being able to access non-public members). It's just a bit more elegant to write and use such a function.